# Multiprocessing Worker won't start next job

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run multiple simulations using the multiprocessing module in python (3.7). I'm using a pool of workers. They'll finish their first simulation in good time (the function will end) however they won't start another simulation for a significant amount of time (much longer the length of one simulation). Python is using the CPU and memory during this time but I don't understand what on.

I've pasted in the multiprocessing code and output below.
The `run_simulation` function is too long and calls too many other functions to paste into this question. It may be the problem though. I've tried removing parts of the function that I thought could be the issue but I couldn't find the issue. The simulation saves its result to a file. I thought that could be the cause of the issue, however I removed that part of the function and the issue persisted.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))))

from simulation import run_simulation
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp


def function_wrapper(idx, sim_type):
    run_start_time = datetime.now()
    filename = "matlab_data\\a" + run_start_time.strftime("%y%m%d_%H_") + str(idx).zfill(4) + ".mat"
    print("Starting:", idx, "-", sim_type, "   Start time:", run_start_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
          "   Filename:", filename)
    try:
        output = run_simulation(scenario=sim_type, save_data_to_mat_file=False,
                                matlab_file_name=filename)

        print("Completed: " + str(idx) + "-" + sim_type +
              "   Finish time:" + datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") +
              "   Duration:" + str(datetime.now() - run_start_time) +
              "   Filename:" + filename)
        return output
    except Exception as error: # Just so one random error doesn't derail an overnight run
        print("Error: " + str(idx) + "-" + sim_type +
              "   Finish time:" + datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") +
              "   Duration:" + str(datetime.now() - run_start_time) +
              "   Filename:" + filename)
        print(error)
        return None


def multiple_runs(use_parallel=True):
    sim_start_time = datetime.now()
    print("Started at:" + sim_start_time.strftime("%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S"))

    n_sets_of_sims = 30
    sim_names = ["TestSim"]
    sims_to_run = sim_names * n_sets_of_sims

    if use_parallel:
        with mp.get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
            indicies = range(len(sims_to_run))
            output = pool.starmap_async(function_wrapper, zip(indicies, sims_to_run))

            try:
                output.get(timeout=600)
            except Exception as error:
                print("We lacked patience and got a multiprocessing.TimeoutError")
                print(error)

    else: # Run Sequentially
        for idx, sim_name in enumerate(sims_to_run):
            function_wrapper(idx, sim_name)

    print("Finished at: " + datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%y - %H:%M:%S") + "     " +
          "Duration: " + str(datetime.now() - sim_start_time))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    multiple_runs(use_parallel=True)
```

Here is some example output:

```
Started at:20/06/21 - 14:51:01
Main loop process id: 15720 
Starting: 0 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:07    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0000.mat
Starting: 1 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:08    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0001.mat
Starting: 2 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:08    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0002.mat
Starting: 3 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:08    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0003.mat
Starting: 4 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:08    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0004.mat
Starting: 5 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:08    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0005.mat
Starting: 6 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:08    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0006.mat
Starting: 7 - TestSim    Start time: 14:51:08    Filename: matlab_data\a210620_14_0007.mat
Completed: 1-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:51   Duration:0:00:43.349098   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0001.mat
Completed: 3-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:51   Duration:0:00:43.218098   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0003.mat
Completed: 0-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:51   Duration:0:00:43.799112   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0000.mat
Completed: 2-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:51   Duration:0:00:43.709106   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0002.mat
Completed: 4-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:52   Duration:0:00:43.876114   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0004.mat
Completed: 7-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:52   Duration:0:00:43.674106   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0007.mat
Completed: 6-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:52   Duration:0:00:43.852111   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0006.mat
Completed: 5-TestSim   Finish time:14:51:52   Duration:0:00:44.036120   Filename:matlab_data\a210620_14_0005.mat
We lacked patience and got a multiprocessing.TimeoutError

Finished at: 20/06/21 - 15:01:02     Duration: 0:10:00.398742

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior with a simple slow function like ```n=100000000; while n>1: n-=1```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: I changed the simulation to return None.**

The simulation function was returning the results of the simulation. This is quite a large dictionary. When I changed it to return None, the problem stopped. I don't need the simulation result to be returned as it was being saved to a file instead.

It's no longer a problem for me however I don't know why this made a difference and would be interested if anyone has any suggestions.